# Save data structured data as part of java executable

Tags: java, jar

Suppose I have a fixed huge list of numbers but I have to convert it to a tree and then perform some computations based on the input. I'm going to create an executable that would accept queries as input. 
Can I skip reconstructing the tree again from the list and include the tree, in the right data structures, as part of the executable?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: You'll get better answers when you post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and ask specific questions about what is not working in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use:
getClass().getResource(/path/inside/jar);
Or you can use: getClass().getResourceAsStream(/path/inside/jar);

Suppose your jar looks like this:

```
Jar/
     MANIFEST/
     tree/
            one/
                   part1.dat
     main/
            main.class
```

Then to get part1.dat you would use:

```
getClass().getResource("/tree/one/part1.dat");
```